# pos_hint does not move custom widget in FloatLayout kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to setup a day and month display.

In the **planner.kv** file I can't get the `Telldate` child widget to work with `pos_hint` in `FloatLayout` but it seems to be working fine with `Button`.

I'm not sure if i've set up `FloatLayout` properly or if I'm going about it in the wrong way.

I understand that `Telldate` is a custom widget and a child widget when inside `FloatLayout` unless I'm wrong about that.
Everything else is working as intended

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from time import strftime
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Telldate(Widget):
   todayday = ObjectProperty('')

   def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.todayday= strftime('%A')

class PlannerApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PlannerApp().run()
```

planner.kv

```
<Telldate>:
    Button:
        size:(50,50)
        text:self.parent.todayday


FloatLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'ay'
        size_hint:(None,None)    
        pos_hint: { 'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.8}

    Telldate:
        size_hint:(None,None)
        pos_hint: { 'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.8}
```

I'm using python V3.6.2 and Kivy v1.10.0 with IDLE V3.6.2
Thanks for your patience!

**----Edit1:---**

using

```
class Telldate(FloatLayout):
```

instead of

```
class Telldate(Widget):
```

allows me to set hint_size because i'm now inheriting FloatLayout properties and not widget properties but still doesn't allow hint_pos to be set.
The rest of the code is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I learnt was that widgets don't inherit properties of layouts which is where my troubles began with `Telldate(Widget)`, i found this in the documentations for widget.

Using `Telldate(FloatLayout)` instead and calling(not sure if the right terminology) the `class Telldate` via `<Telldate>` into kivy solved my issue.

And then creating FloatLayout for whenever I want to call a custom widget as in the .kv file

planner.kv

```
<Tellday@Label>:

    size:(50,50)        



<Telldate>:
    FloatLayout:                
        Tellday:
            size_hint:( None,None)              
            text: self.parent.parent.todayday
            pos_hint:{'top': 0.5,'right':0.5}
```

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from time import strftime
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Telldate(FloatLayout):
   todayday= ObjectProperty('')
 #  todaymonth = ObjectProperty('')

   def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.todayday=strftime('%A')

       self.todayday= strftime('%A')
     #  self.todaymonth= strftime('%b')

class PlannerApp(App):

       def build(self):
         return Telldate()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PlannerApp().run()
```

hope this helps someone!

Comment: <Telldate>:
    FloatLayout: 

The FloatLayout here is extraneous since TellDate is already a FloatLayout. Your initial issue was that you were trying to inherit directly from Widget (which you typically shouldn't do).